# How delegates and callback work?

Tags: c#, winapi, delegates, callback

I don't fully understand these topics.

I work with several WinAPI methods

```
public delegate bool Win32Callback(IntPtr hwnd, ref IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32.Dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr parentHandle, Win32Callback callback, IntPtr lParam);
```

and

```
public static bool BrowserEnumChildrenCallback(IntPtr hWnd, ref IntPtr lParam)
{
    if (hWndMeetsConditions)
        return true;
    //code
    return false;
}
```

Is it possible get `hWnd` for which was returned true from `BrowserEnumChildrenCallback`?

```
Win32Callback callBack = new MainWindow.Win32Callback(BrowserEnumChildrenCallback);
if (EnumChildWindows(hWnd, callBack, hWnd))
{
    //here
}
```

Comment: What is the question? - can you be more specific.

Comment: @Niklas Last 'code'. How get hWnd for which was returned 'true'. Now it isn't the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several problems:

- The delegate declaration is wrong, the last argument is IntPtr, not *ref IntPtr*.
- The callback should return true to continue iterating, you're doing it backwards
- Write GC.KeepAlive(callBack) after the EnumChildWindows() call to prevent the delegate object from getting garbage collected.
- Don't use the return value of EnumChildWindows(), the SDK docs note that it is unused.  You detect failure by not finding the window.

Answering the actual question: store the window handle in a field of your class.  Thus:

```
private IntPtr windowFound;

private void iterateChildWindows(IntPtr parent) {
    windowFound = IntPtr.Zero;
    var callBack = new MainWindow.Win32Callback(BrowserEnumChildrenCallback);
    EnumChildWindows(parent, callBack, IntPtr.Zero);
    GC.KeepAlive(callBack);
    if (windowFound != IntPtr.Zero) {
       // etc..
    }
}

private bool BrowserEnumChildrenCallback(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam)
{
    if (hWndMeetsConditions(hWnd)) {
        windowFound = hWnd;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

A lambda works well too.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<IntPtr> _hwnds = new List<IntPtr>();
public static bool BrowserEnumChildrenCallback(IntPtr hWnd, ref IntPtr lParam) 
{     
     if (hWndMeetsConditions)         
     {
          _hwnds.Add( hWnd );
          return true;     
     }

     //code     
     return false; 
} 

Win32Callback callBack = new MainWindow.Win32Callback(BrowserEnumChildrenCallback);  
if (EnumChildWindows(hWnd, callBack, hWnd))  
{      
    // here  
    // you have it in _hwnd
}
```